# Oculus Rift and DirectX11 viewports

Tags: c++, directx, oculus

I have been working with the Oculus Rift and got it all set up to use in my project. Now I just need to  set up two viewports. As the documentation states in Psuedocode.

```
// Render Left Eye Half
SetViewport(0, 0, HResolution/2, VResolution);
SetProjection(LeftEyeProjectionMatrix); 
RenderScene();

// Render Right Eye Half 
SetViewport(HResolution/2, 0, HResolution, VResolution); 
SetProjection(RightEyeProjectionMatrix); 
RenderScene();
```

I've googled around quite a lot and am not getting results. Can someone explain how, direct me to some tutorials, or source code on how to do this with DirectX11? Prefferably explain how to split the viewport though.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? You can set the viewport with [`RSSetViewports()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476480(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Documentation and available samples are horrible.
I am stuck at the same issue, trying  to get a simple a DX11 example (triangle) DK2 ready.
The docs are useless and the only "small" example is basically a whole 3d game engine.